# Indian Citizen travelling from Vietnam to India via Bangkok

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, vietnam, bangkok

I am travelling from Vietnam to India via Bangkok. 
My flight details are as below:
Vietnam - Bangkok : Vietnam Airlines
Bangkok - Mumbai : Air India
Layover period at Bangkok : 2h20m

I would like to know:
1. Does the baggage get checked in all the way through to India or do I need to collect the same at Bangkok?
2. Do I need a visa for Bangkok? If yes, then can it be done it advance or do I need to get it done at Bangkok airport only, as the layover period is very less?

Regards,
Ashish K

Comment: Is this entire journey part of one booking, or did you book the two flights separately?

Comment: Its a single booking.